Spring boot test can not cast GenericWebApplicationContext
I'm new with spring boot. I follow clean architecture with spring boot in this link https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-clean-architecture In this tutorial, spring context load bean with bean factory. Then when I want to test API with MockMvc. I write test class follow this:
@SpringBootTest
class ApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    void contextLoads(){

    }
}

But run testcase got error: class org.springframework.web.context.support.GenericWebApplicationContext cannot be cast to class org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext (org.springframework.web.context.support.GenericWebApplicationContext and org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
Any can explain this error or config bean in Spring boot test?

Annotate your test class with @AutoConfigureMockMvc as well.
